# How to iterate through attributes of child and rename it Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this markup. I am trying to write jquery selectors to get all element inside template order list whose name has Works string. My requirement is that I have multiple ordered list. If I will delete any list I want to rearrange indexes in name attribute.

```
<ol class="template"> 
    <li> 
        <span class="label" name="Works[0].Id"></span> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="textBox" type="text" value="" name="Works[0].Body">
    </li>                     
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="" name="Works[0].IsCompleted">                         
        <input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete">                      
    </li>                 
</ol>

<ol class="template"> 
    <li> 
        <span class="label" name="Works[1].Id"></span> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="textBox" type="text" value="" name="Works[1].Body">
    </li>                     
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="" name="Works[1].IsCompleted">                         
        <input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete">                      
    </li>                 
</ol>

<ol class="template"> 
    <li> 
        <span class="label" name="Works[2].Id"></span> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="textBox" type="text" value="" name="Works[2].Body">
    </li>                     
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="" name="Works[2].IsCompleted">                         
        <input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete">                      
    </li>                 
</ol>
```

My approach is to after I will remove any order list i.e. after click of delete button. I will take every ordered list and by iterating through I will change index for 0 to length of list. But I am not getting proper selector to catch elements inside an ordered list whose name attribute has value starts with Works. Please suggest some better selector.

Comment: Where is the JavaScript attempt?

Answer (score 0):

The selector you want is:

```
$("ol.template [name^=Works]")
```

This is the jQuery [Attribute Starts With](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector.

By the way, `name` is not a valid attribute on `<span>` elements. It should only be used for the following elements:

`<button>, <form>, <fieldset>, <iframe>, <input>, <keygen>, <object>, <output>, <select>, <textarea>, <map>, <meta>, <param>`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

Comment: Thanks!! Can we get this for every template. i.e I want to loop through each template.

Comment: You can use it any time you want to find all the elements with an attribute that starts the same.

Comment: Did you mean $(this).find("[name^=Works]") ?

Comment: Yeah, that works for finding all the template elements under the current element.

Answer (score 0):

here is pure javascript working with majors browsers

```
var ol = document.getElementsByTagName('ol');
var temp = ol.getElementsByClassName('template');
for(var i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
if(temp[i].name.indexOf('Works')==0){ // if name attribute start with 'Work'
//if(temp[i].name.indexOf('Works') > -1){    => if name attribute contains 'Work'
//if(temp[i].name.indexOf('Works') == -1){  => if name attribute is not contains 'Work'
//if(temp[i].name.indexOf('Works') == temp[i].name.length - 'Works'.length - 1){  => if name attribute is ended with 'Work'
// now play with with temp[i]
temp[i].style.background = 'yellow';
}
}
```